# How to animate a bitmap

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, bitmap

Is there a easier way on how can I animate my bitmap like an animation drawable? I study about sprites but it seems that it is much difficult than I thought.

**UPDATE** heres my code:

```
mAnimLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menu_anim);
mAnimLogo.setImageResource(R.animator.menu_title);
mAnimLogo.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mAnimLogo.getDrawable();
mAnimation.start();
```

and on my ondraw.

```
resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resizedbitmap, Bitwidth,
        Bitheight, true);
// draw bitmap
canvas.drawBitmap(resizedbitmap, (currentX * totalCellWidth)
        + (cellWidth / 20), (currentY * totalCellHeight)
        + (cellWidth / 20), ball);
```

then Ive got a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Hi Maria, 

I am not entirely sure I understand your questions. I hope you understand the difference between bitmap and vertor images: 
http://etc.usf.edu/techease/win/images/what-is-the-difference-between-bitmap-and-vector-images/

you may also be interested in reading up about: SVGs (Scalable Vector Graphics)

I am not sure what kind of animation you have in mind, but you can try: Sprites for easy image manipulation or look at SGV for more complex image animations.

Comment: seems that there is no easier way to animate a bitmap than to make a sprite. :(

Comment: You cannot mix Animation drawable and onDraw() methods. If you are doing AnimationDrawable than all you actual drawing is happening inside AnimationDrawable class and onDraw will merely talk to AnimationDrawable and call it repeatedly. You can do one of two: 1) Make your own view containing Bitmap (no need for ImageView) and paint it yourself posting time delayed invalidate. 2) override AnimationDrawable and do custom drawing in its onDraw method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged your question as Android Eclipse - it is rather easy on Android platform.
There is:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html
and after you done that you need to apply it to one of your views (by hand in draw(Canvas) method) or some Views do support Drawable as a background. Should be fairly simple and nothing to do with sprites and SVG (not SGV)

Comment: sir i do have view class and also a ondraw method. my problem is i dont know how can i use animation drawable to subtitute the bitmap that i had drawn on view class.

Comment: Since you already have onDraw and know how to do Canvas.drawBitmap(…) you can just use static Handler handler = new Handler(); in your View class and Runnable invalidate() = new Runnable() { … invalidate(); } and than from you onDraw(Canvas c) { … handler.postDelayed(invalidate, milliseconds); … }